# Python - Find an element in a List of Lists which is within a given range

Tags: python

Lets say I have a List like this

```
numbersList = [[18, 1, 4], [6, 20, 32]]
```

I want to find the element in this `numbersList` that is within the range of `3 to 7` as such `3 <= x <= 7`

Expected Output: `4, 6`

Whats the best way of doing this without a `for` loop?

Comment: There are many values in your list which satisfy that requirement. What is your expected output?

Comment: @Nick Wow can't believe i forgot to put that. Okay I've changed the values in the list and added an expected output. Check it out :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any solution you find for this will involve a for loop, whether explicit or implicit, as you have to iterate over all the values to find the matching ones. One way is a list comprehension:

```
numbersList = [[18, 1, 4], [6, 20, 32]]
f = [n for l in numbersList for n in l if 3 <= n <= 7]
# [4, 6]
```